# React Router not working with multiple fragments

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to implement side bar and wrap them in a div only for few routes. The other routes should not be having the sidebar.

all the pages from top was working except the * wildcard route. Console it says React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  withRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/header";

import LoginPage from "./pages/login";
import DashboardPage from "./pages/dashboard";
import NotfoundPage from "./pages/notfound";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage} />
        <main className="dashboardMain">
          <React.Fragment>
            <SideBar />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/dashboard"
              component={withRouter(DashboardPage)}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        </main>
        <Route path="*" component={NotfoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: is main supposed to be a div? otherwise I can't see it being imported if its a component

Comment: main is the html5 tag not a div. But i replaced that to div. Still didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once have stumbled the same issue. Maybe because we didn't suppose to have **nested** element in between `Route` (I'm not sure about this tho). Anyway, this is the **fixes** I did to my system:-

- separate **additional** & **conditional** element in different `component`.
- create a **new** `component` which gonna act as a **parent** OR **wrapper** for all our `Switch` & `Route`.
- from there we can determine which `Route` should have **sidebar** & which don't.

For the following example, I use `Context API` which **oversee** whether `user` already `login` or not. Only **loggedIn user** will have access to **sidebar**. To make this work, We're gonna need to make some of our `Route` **protected**. See the implementation below:-

- in `App.js` (We will import `Nav` as new external **parent** or **wrapper** `component` for all our `Switch` & `Route`. We only have `Dashboard` component be **protected**. Only accessible for **loggedIn user**):-

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthState } from "./contexts/AuthState";
import ProtectedRoute from "./comps/ProtectedRoute";
import Nav from "./comps/Nav";
import Login from "./comps/Login";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <Router>
        {/* Nav is an external parent component */}
        <Nav>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={() => "Home page!"} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={() => "About page!"} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <ProtectedRoute
              path="/dashboard"
              component={() => "Dashboard page!"}
            />
            <Route path="*" component={() => "Not Found page!"} />
          </Switch>
        </Nav>
      </Router>
    </AuthState>
  );
}
```

- in `Nav` (here we will receive `children` as `props` for `Nav` component - which are actually all our `Switch` & `Route` from `App.js`. In addition, we also do **conditional** `statement` here to only display **sidebar** for **loggedIn user**. Else, we'll just display the **content** (`children` we received) of the `component` that get **rendered**):-

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthState";
import { logOut } from "../contexts/AuthAction";

const Nav = ({ children }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useAuth();
  const { auth } = authState;

  const [isLogout, setIsLogout] = useState(false);

  // handle logout
  useEffect(() => {
    (() => {
      if (isLogout) {
        logOut(authDispatch);

        // reset state
        setIsLogout(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [isLogout]);

  return (
    <>
      <ul
        style={{
          listStyle: "none",
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center"
        }}
      >
        <li style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
          <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
          <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
        </li>
        {!auth && (
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
      {/* condition happen here
      display sidebar for loggedin user
      else just display content (children) */}
      {auth ? (
        // display content with sidebar
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex"
          }}
        >
          <ul
            style={{
              listStyle: "none",
              margin: 0,
              padding: 10,
              width: "20%",
              minHeight: "100vh",
              backgroundColor: "grey"
            }}
          >
            <li style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
              <NavLink to="/dashboard">Dashboard</NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button onClick={() => setIsLogout(true)}>Logout</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div
            style={{
              padding: 10,
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "lightyellow"
            }}
          >
            <h2 style={{ margin: "0 0 20px 0", padding: 0 }}>Content </h2>
            {children}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        // just display content without sidebar
        children
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

You can refer to this working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-elion-08h6s?file=/src/App.js) of said example use above.

Comment: Glad to help then